# Hoverable Message

Tags: comments, posters

I have been unable to find a way to create a hoverable message in LaTeX that displays when the cursor is placed over it. I would like to include mathematical expressions such as \begin{align}, [ ], for the proof of theorems. I am using overleaf can you suggest a solution?

[image]

Comment: I think I've seen something like this before, but I can't find it at the moment. I wonder if this helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439451/is-there-a-way-to-put-an-expandable-or-click-here-to-show-text-section-in-a

Comment: I do not want the message to occupy the space :/ thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Hope `pdfcomment.sty` suits for you.

Comment: I see this is the same as my photo! I tried and this can't write math mode inside :/

Comment: Maybe this could help: [Tooltip that works with all pdf readers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155518)

Comment: Another tooltip question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304131/how-to-avoid-hyperlinks-with-usepackagetooltipacro